# Start Date Range parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

When I set up my SSRS report originally I set it up to look at the current day so my where clause in my query was:

```
Where
trunc(START_DAY) >= current_date -1 And 
trunc(START_DAY) <= current_date
```

Now I want to add parameters to select just the "START_DAY."
How would I go about setting this up?

Comment: There are a few things you will need to add to your question. `1.` Show a sample of your data. `2.` Explain what data type "START_DATE" is. `3.` Show example values from @From and @To and explain what data types they are.

Comment: @AlanSchofield my original ask was over complicating thing so I changed my ask.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using Oracle where the TRUNC function is converting your datetime to a date.

In this case you would set up a date parameter in SSRS. You can add a default date of today or yesterday.

Then, in the SSRS dataset, add the parameter to your Oracle query.

```
Where TRUNC(START_DAY) = :DATE_PARAM
```

You may need to map the parameter manually in the Parameters tab of the dataset.